# current_page_item is missing inside wp_nav_menu

Tags: functions, menus, css

I'm using the function `wp_nav_menu` like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                         'container' => false,
                         'echo' => true,
                         'before' => '',
                         'after' => '',
                         'link_before' => '',
                         'link_after' => '',
                         'depth' => 0,
                         'walker' => new my_walker())
                         ); ?>



class my_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li class="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . '>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<div>';
           $append = '</div>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
               $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }


            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= '<p>'.$args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after.'</p>';
            $item_output .= $prepend;
            $item_output .= $append;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
            }
}
```

But in this menu the class `current_page_item` is missing. Is there something wrong in my code? How can I add this class? 
Thanks!

Comment: So, you have the `current_page_item` class if you use the default walker?

Comment: No, the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually using a *custom nav menu*, why are you not just outputting `wp_page_menu()` directly?

## Problem

As-implemented, your walker will *never be executed* (or, more accurately, you can't *control* whether or not it is executed), because you're not passing `'theme_location'` (correct usage) or `'menu'` (sub-optimal usage) to the args array.

Here's how the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) output works:

1. WordPress looks for `'menu'` defined in the args array. This value corresponds to the slug of a *user-created custom nav menu*. So if the user creates a Menu named "Short Header Menu", the slug would be `'short-header-menu'`, which would correspond to `'menu' => 'short-header'menu'`. If the menu is found, it is used.
2. WordPress looks for `'theme_location'` defined in the args array. This value corresponds to the user-defined custom nav menu *assigned by the user to the Theme Location*. So, if the user creates a Menu named "Short Header Menu", and assigns it to the (Theme-defined) Theme Location "Primary Menu" (defined by the Theme via `register_nav_menus( array( 'primary-menu' => "Primary Menu 0 0`), the `'short-header-menu'` would be the menu returned. If found, it is used.
3. If neither `'menu'` nor `'theme_location'` is defined the args array, WordPress queries all of the user-created custom nav menus. If the user has created custom nav menus, WordPress uses the first one that has menu items.
4. If all of the above fail, WordPress outputs the fallback menu, as defined via `'fallback_cb'`.

So, in your example, you're not passing either `'menu'` or `'theme_location'` to the args array. If the user (e.g. you) hasn't created any custom nav menus, then WordPress is outputting the `'fallback_cb'`, which by definition is `wp_page_menu()`.

Now, `wp_nav_menu()` passes its `$args` array to the fallback function, but [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) doesn't accept a `'walker'` parameter. So your custom walker is being ignored.

## Solution

1. Properly register custom nav menu Theme locations, via `register_nav_menus()`
2. Create custom nav menus, via `Appearance -> Menus`
3. Assign a custom nav menu to a registered Theme Location
4. Pass the `'theme_location'` parameter to your `wp_nav_menu()` `$args` array

## Addendum

Note, if the sole purpose of your custom walker is to add the `.current-page-item` class, then you don't need your custom walker at all. The `wp_nav_menu()` classes are backwards-compatible with `wp_page_menu()`, which means that [the `.current-page-item` class is *already output* by `wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Backward_Compatibility_with_wp_page_menu.28.29).

Comment: Thus the Walker class is wrong?

Comment: More accurately, the Walker class is *irrelevant*.

Comment: But I need this class, because it allows me to customize the menu. Anyway, before adding that class the menu worked perfectly, namely the `css` class `current_page_item` were present.

Comment: "*But I need this class*" - `wp_nav_menu()`, *by default*, outputs the `.current-page-item` class. You don't need a Walker to add it.

Comment: I used the Walker class because I had to modify the menu, namely I added a div in every `li` tag..

Comment: So, did you attempt the solution steps? Did they work?

Comment: I tried the solution steps, but nothing change..

Comment: Please **edit your question** to describe *what you tried*, what you **expected** to happen, and what **actually** happened. A live link demonstrating the problem would be very helpful, also.